# Windows Git Bash shell cannot find commands?

Tags: windows, git, bash, shell

I have recently been screwing around with Windows Git Bash shell to try and force its `~` to not be my mapped network drive `Z:` and instead something more logical and useful. To do so I tried to edit `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\profile`, upon saving my changes and restarting it seems that GitBash now cannot find most all commands.

[image]

**What happened and how do I fix this?**

I'd also like to note that I could not edit `profile` with Notepad++ or any other text editor, each complained that the file was already opened elsewhere on the computer when trying to save the changes. To edit the file I had to use `vim` within Git Bash. Also once I saved these inserts (`HOME="C:\Users\..\__GitBash\`) I could not view the changes with Notepad++, the file modified date didn't even change (though oddly enough it seems that `~` is now `C:\Users\...\Documents`; BUT NOT `C:\Users\...\Documents\__GitBash\`)... Also note I do not have administrator privileges on this computer.

Comment: Check your `$PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, if your `$PATH` does not include a reference to `git.exe`:

First, echo to see if it does contain a `git.exe` reference:

```
echo "$PATH"
```

If not, add the path using this command:

```
PATH="$PATH;C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin"
```

Make sure that the path correctly addresses an existing file on your system, too.

Comment: That last part should probably read `C:\Windows\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin`. The name of the program should not be in the path.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think you're correct, but I'll double-check. Edit made

Comment: In `cmd`, do `setx path "%path%;C:\Windows\Program Files(x86)\Git\bin"`

Comment: In GitBash my `PATH` does include `...\Git\bin` (EDIT) It is also included in my Windows `PATH`.

Comment: Changing the directory to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ ` has seemed to fix the issue. The directory you have in the answer does not exist on my computer.